# Alternative for an if then else statement

Tags: java, hashmap, control-flow

Can anyone assist me with an alternative to if-then-else statements for control flow? Or advise on a good article?  From what I've seen, some use mapping or enums. Trouble I'm having is that I have multiple conditions i.e. `if (condition1 && condition2 && condition3)...` and I need to do this for several permutations and all 3 variables need to be validated.

Please can someone point me in the right direction?

```
else if (String.Utils.isNotEmpty(payload.getKeyChange2TokenNumber()) &&
         String.Utils.isEmpty(payload.getKeyChange1TokenNumber()) &&
         String.Utils.isEmpty(payload.getKeyChange2TokenNumber())
{
```

So with no if-then-else statements, how can I implement a hashmap to determine what to return in place of the if-then-else statements?

```
    return String.format(return value dependant on outcome of validation) 
}
```

Comment: It's very hard to make a suggestion without seeing your current attempt.

Comment: I didn't get that, sorry. Could you make it concrete by showing the if-else statement that you want to replace? And maybe elaborate on why you want that?

Comment: Sorry about that, this is my code snippet that I need to optimise...

Comment: this is my code snippet
else if (String.Utils.isNotEmpty(payload.getKeyChange2TokenNumber()) && String.Utils.isEmpty(payload.getKeyChange1TokenNumber()) && String.Utils.isEmpty(payload.getKeyChange2TokenNumber()) {
return String.format(return value dependant on outcome of validation) }

Comment: I'm a junior and I've joined a team that isn't a fan of the if then else control flow...

Comment: Duplicate of the question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61578485/a-hashmap-alternative-to-the-if-then-else-statement-in-java

Comment: Since by now you have got an answer to [your rewording of the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61578485/a-hashmap-alternative-to-the-if-then-else-statement-in-java), I suppose that we can leave this question closed (even though @NisseEngström’s edit has made it clearer).